# Is it OK to have multiple TXT records for a single domain containing different SPF entries?

Tags: domain-name-system, email, spf

A remote recipient domain is rejecting mail on the grounds of SPF and I think it's because the sender has SPF configured incorrectly.

When I run dig, I see:

```
[fooadm@box ~]# dig @8.8.8.8 -t TXT foosender.com

; <<>> DiG 9.3.6-P1-RedHat-9.3.6-20.P1.el5_8.6 <<>> @8.8.8.8 -t TXT foosender.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options:  printcmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 30608
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;foosender.com.              IN      TXT

;; ANSWER SECTION:
foosender.com.       14039   IN      TXT     "v=spf1 include:spf.foo1.com -all"
foosender.com.       14039   IN      TXT     "v=spf1 include:_spf.bob.foo2.com -all"

;; Query time: 26 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Tue Jan  7 09:45:38 2014
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 146
```

Is this a valid setup? It seems strange to me that there are two separate records (each with hard fails).  Shouldn't everything be in a single record?

I would expect the proper TXT record to be:

`v=spf1 include:spf.foo1.com include:_spf.bob.foo2.com -all`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No.  You are right.  See [RFC 4408, section 4.5](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4408.txt).

> 1. Records that do not begin with a version section of exactly
>        "v=spf1" are discarded.  Note that the version section is
>        terminated either by an SP character or the end of the record.  A
>        record with a version section of "v=spf10" does not match and must
>        be discarded.
> 2. If any records of type SPF are in the set, then all records of
>        type TXT are discarded.
>
>    After the above steps, there should be exactly one record remaining
>      and evaluation can proceed.  **If there are two or more records remaining, then check_host() exits 
>      immediately with the result of "PermError".**
>
>    If no matching records are returned, an SPF client MUST assume that
>      the domain makes no SPF declarations.  SPF processing MUST stop and
>      return "None".

Comment: As of April 2014 there is [RFC 7208](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7208) which obsoletes RFC 4408. Records of type SPF have been deprecated in favor of TXT type ones `SPF records MUST be published as a DNS TXT (type 16) Resource Record
   (RR) [RFC1035] only.` (see [RFC 7208, section 3.1](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7208#section-3.1)). I am going to try a new answer based on this.

Answer (score 5):

This SPF setup is not valid. In case there are multiple records found, the record selection should produce an error as result. See [RFC 7208, section 4.5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7208#section-4.5) on selecting records:

> If the resultant record set includes
> more than one record, check_host() produces the "permerror" result.